# Unable to create XSLT extension in Javascript or Jython with Ant

Tags: javascript, ant, jython, xalan

I am using Ant 1.8 to run some XSLTs on documents in a folder. Ant uses Xalan to process the XSLT. The jobs run ok, I get a bunch of transformed output files corresponding to the input ones.

The problem is when trying to extend XSL with either Javascript or Jython functions to process some tricky strings. Either Javascript or Jython would do, whichever works first, but the moment neither does.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:jython-extension="http://www.jython.org/"
xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
exclude-result-prefixes="lxslt xalan"
xmlns:gotofritz="GotoFritz">

<xalan:component prefix="gotofritz" functions="test">
    <xalan:script lang="javascript">
    function test(){
        return '********* JS WORKS *******';
    }
    </xalan:script>
</xalan:component>

<lxslt:component prefix="jython-extension" functions="test">
    <lxslt:script lang="jpython">
    def test():
        return "**** JYTHON WORKS ****"
    </lxslt:script>
</lxslt:component>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="gotofritz:test()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="jython-extension:test()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have downloaded bsf.jar and javascript.har, as well as the latest xalan jar, and moved them to /usr/share/ant/lib - I am on OS X.

The javscript fails with "Error! Cannot find class 'GotoFritz'." and "Error! Cannot find external method 'GotoFritz.test' (must be public)."

The Jython fails with
Warning! Unable to resolve call to function 'http://www.jython.org/:test'.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: test, method: template$dot$3 signature: (Lcom/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/DOM;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/dtm/DTMAxisIterator;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;I)V) Expecting to find integer on stack
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.getTransletInstance(TemplatesImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.newTransformer(TemplatesImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.createTransformer(TraXLiaison.java:319)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.transform(TraXLiaison.java:177)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.process(XSLTProcess.java:852)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.execute(XSLTProcess.java:388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

It looks to me that Xalan is treating both extensions as Java instead of using BSF. Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me using this stylesheet (xalanext.xsl):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
                xmlns:js-extension="http://example.com"
                xmlns:jython-extension="http://www.jython.org/"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xalan js-extension jython-extension">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xalan:component prefix="js-extension" functions="test">
    <xalan:script lang="javascript">
      function test(){
      return '********* JS WORKS *******';
      }
    </xalan:script>
  </xalan:component>

  <xalan:component prefix="jython-extension" functions="test">
    <xalan:script lang="jython">
def test():
    return "**** JYTHON WORKS ****"
    </xalan:script>
  </xalan:component>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
      <javascript><xsl:value-of select="js-extension:test()"/></javascript>
      <jython><xsl:value-of select="jython-extension:test()"/></jython>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my Ant build file:

```
<project name="xalanext" default="runxslt">
  <path id="xslt.processor.classpath">
    <pathelement path="xalan.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="bsf.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="js.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="jython.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
  </path>

  <target name="runxslt">
    <xslt classpathref="xslt.processor.classpath" 
      in="test.xml" out="out.xml"
      basedir="." destdir="."
      extension=".xml" style="xalanext.xsl">
    </xslt>
  </target>
</project>
```

test.xml is a small "dummy" document that just contains `<root/>`.

Resulting output in out.xml:

```
<result>
<javascript>********* JS WORKS *******</javascript>
<jython>**** JYTHON WORKS ****</jython>
</result>
```

Comments:

- bsf.jar is from BSF 2.4.0. Using bsf-all-3.1.jar from BSF 3.1 gives me `org.apache.xalan.extensions.ObjectFactory$ConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not found`.
- The Jython script language is given as `jython` (not `jpython`) in the stylesheet.
- The definition of the `test()` Jython function begins in the leftmost column (Jython is picky about whitespace).
- A JavaScript implementation is needed (something called "javascript.har" is mentioned in the question, but I don't know what that is). js.jar contains the [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) engine. Rhino is bundled in Oracle's Java 1.6 and later, but I was unable to make it work unless js.jar was on the classpath.
- I had to add the commons-logging jar to the classpath to avoid `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`.
- Xalan's serializer.jar must be in the same directory as xalan.jar to avoid `XSLT Error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError): org/apache/xml/serializer/ExtendedContentHandler`.

Comment: That looks good - I shall test it and get back to you, thanks!